# Snort 3.0 Error: Command 'daq-config' not found

Tags: snort

I have been trying to install snort for days now and I am at my complete wits end. I am currently on the **FIRST STEP** of this entire process; installing libdaq. Everything goes well, up until when I try to verify if daq-config has been successfully created, and it hasn't.

Any help is seriously appreciated, I really need this to work for an assignment and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. This has wasted multiple days of potential progress on what is seemingly a simple part of the entire process and it's been incredibly stressing on me.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on Virtualbox.

I make sure to install all the needed dependencies

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libpcap-dev libpcre3-dev libdumbnet-dev bison flex zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev autoconf libtool pkg-config
```

I then download the most recent libdaq file from the snort website, I then tar -xvzf that file, access the file, then I do the usual

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

then checking if daq-config has been made via `daq-config --version` and daq-config `--list-daq-modules`, both come up with errors. Checking to see if the file is made via the built in file explorer